# Mouse events between two ItemsContorl elements

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Take a look at below code. BoxControl has MouseLeftButtonDown/MouseLeftButtonUp events and those work fine when the mouse is clicked on 
the box control other than when the mouse is clicked on below text block. I want MouseLeftButtonDown/MouseLeftButtonUp events of BoxControl 
to work when the mouse is clicked on below textblock. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected. Your `BoxControl` is the one which has the `click` events so that is the only control which is listening for these events, and `TextBlock` isn't.

There are two things you can do:

1) Add the `TextBlock` in your `BoxControl`

OR

2) Add the `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events on your current `TextBlock` and get these textblock_MouseClickHandlers to delegate to the event handlers for the `BoxControl`

Comment: Thanks, Can u explain more about your second choice. This TextBlock is defined in Generic.xaml. How can I implement your suggested mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You should hook into the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp events instead.  Make sure to mark them as handled if you don't want them to bubble up any further.